# Create sample data on devise user create in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am building a Ruby on Rails app where `researchers` can run `studies`.

I would like a new sample study to be created for a researcher (user) when they first sign up. This is a bit different to a db seed since it will need to dynamically create the study for this particular user, rather than once for the entire database.

I'm using Devise for user accounts.

What's a good approach for this? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it by overriding the <del>[`Devise::RegistrationsController`](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/registrations_controller.rb)</del>  `Devise::InvitationsController`.

```
# feel free to call this class whatever you want.
class Users::InvitationsController < Devise::InvitationsController
  def create
    # the block is yielded after the resource has been saved
    # but before anything has been rendered.
    super do |user|
      if user.valid?
        user.studies.create(title: 'New study')
      end
    end 
  end
end
```

And then we need to tell Devise to route to our custom controller:

```
# config/routes.rb
devise_for :users, controllers: { 
  registrations: 'users/registrations',
  invitations: 'users/invitations'
}
```

If you want to extract the creation process from the controller you can use a factory method or a [service object](https://blog.engineyard.com/2014/keeping-your-rails-controllers-dry-with-services):

```
class Study < ActiveRecord::Base
  # ...
  def self.create_default(**kwargs)
    # the default options are merged with the keyword arguments
    attrs = {
      title: 'Foo',
      bar: 'Baz'
    }.merge(kwargs)
    study = scoped.build(attrs)
    # lets us pass a block just like .new and .create
    yield study if block_given?
    study
  end
end
```

---

```
# app/controllers/user/registrations_controller.rb
# ...
  def create
    # the block is yielded after the resource has been saved
    # but before anything has been rendered.
    super do |user|
      if user.valid?
        study = user.studies.create_default(baz: 'Something else')
        study.save
      end
    end 
  end
```

Comment: IMHO its a much better idea to do this once on signup rather than every time a user signs into the application.

Comment: For existing users you may want to use a rake task to seed them with a default.

Comment: Nice answer, thank you. At the moment I'm skipping registrations (`devise_for :users, controllers: { registrations: "registrations", invitations: "users/invitations", sessions: "sessions" }, skip: [:registrations]`) because the app is invite only, and uses an invitations controller instead. I put the create code in the sessions controller and that still seems to work okay. Is there anything I should watch out for when doing this?

Comment: In that case I would do the exact same thing but with the InvitationsController, I have edited my answer. I would generally avoid tacking anything onto the sessions controller as it is a very high traffic area in most apps.

Answer (score 1):

config/routes.rb

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => { :sessions => "sessions" }
```

app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb

```
class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  before_action :before_login, only: :create
  after_action :after_login, only: :create

  def before_login
  end

  def after_login
    if current_user.sign_in_count == 1
     User.studies.create(title: 'New study')
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Is it possible to seed the content from a .yml or .rb file instead? There is quite a bit of data.

Comment: You can wrap your import data code into a module. Include (include ModuleName) this module in SessionsController. And you can use all methods from this module in you SessionsController like this ModuleName::method_name.